# pandas update a column with another dataframe columns's cell value with duplicated index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

there are 2 dfs

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a','d','e']},index=[1,2,3,4,5])

ndf = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', '2', '6','e'],
                   'B': ['apple', 'pen', 'sky','duck']},index=[7,8,9,19])
```

df's A column should be updated with ndf's B columns values like this:
if a cell of df'A columns's values==ndf's A columns values,the cell value of df's A column does no update;
otherwise:
df's A column's cell value should be replaced by the ndf's B columns cells values:

e.g.:
after update, A should be like:

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': ['apple', 'b', 'apple','d','duck']},index=[1,2,3,4,5])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `dict` from `ndf`, map it to `df`. Use the result to `combine_first` to `df.A`.

```
df.A.map(dict(zip(ndf.A,ndf.B))).combine_first(df.A)

1    apple
2        b
3    apple
4        d
5     duck

Step by Step

`d= dict(zip(ndf.A,ndf.B))`#Create dict

df['C']= df.A.map(d)# map dict to df.A

df.A=df.C.combine_first(df.A)#Update df.A
```

Comment: This method only takes 30s for a 480MB csv while MrNobody33's method takes 8 hours and gave OOM. Why this method is so extremely fast?

Comment: `dict(zip(ndf.A,ndf.B))` calls two columns to create dict. @MrNobody33 method creates a dict of the whole dataframe and filters out required dataframe. Try run `ndf.set_index('A').to_dict()` and see what I mean. You are doing the right thing, dont go for an answer because of votes. Peaople vote for an answer at times because they know the contributor, or how classy the answer is etc. Some vote based on reputation. Try google `Hottest Pandas Answers` and subject them to speed. People with low reputation are often giving optimized answers than frequent contributors.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a dictionary with `to_dict` and then use `replace`:

```
df.replace(ndf.set_index('A').to_dict()['B'])
```

Output:

```
       A
1  apple
2      b
3  apple
4      d
5   duck
```

---

**Details**:

```
print(ndf.set_index('A'))
A       
a  apple
2    pen
6    sky
e   duck


print(ndf.set_index('A').to_dict())
{'B': {'a': 'apple', '2': 'pen', '6': 'sky', 'e': 'duck'}}


print(ndf.set_index('A').to_dict()['B'])
{'a': 'apple', '2': 'pen', '6': 'sky', 'e': 'duck'}

print(df.replace(ndf.set_index('A').to_dict()['B']))
       A
1  apple
2      b
3  apple
4      d
5   duck
```

Comment: nice and easy to understand! lerant new.